# Como puedo quitar el símbolo q en netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

Cambie el aspecto del netbeans y después le empece a mover para poder regresarlo a como esta cuando lo instalas pero lo termine empeorando aparecieron esos símbolos en el código ya se que no afectan en algo pero es muy molesto, y disculpen si es algo muy básico pero no tengo mucha experiencia en este IDE.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Funciono, se suluciono mi problema con el IDE Netbeans gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bueno...  Se soluciona haciendo clic en el menu en "View" y desactivando "show Non-printable Characters".

Con eso eliminas ese símbolo que solo es visual.